# Didn’t find class “java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture”

Tags: java, android, testing, ui-testing, circleci-2.0

I'm using CircleCI to test an android project - I recently added added a use of a Java 8 api: `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture` and now I'm getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture"`. I'm using the `circleci/android:api-27-alpha` image which I understand [is based on JKD8](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-android/#docker-images).

I've tried printing the java version in the job and it looks fine to me.
[image]

Does anyone have any pointers at what else could be happening?

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture;
at com.jumpitt.workmentor.TestUtils.login(TestUtils.java:24)
at com.jumpitt.workmentor.MainActivityTest.onSyncClicked(MainActivityTest.java:94)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.jumpitt.workmentor.test-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jumpitt.workmentor-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.jumpitt.workmentor-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
... 36 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: What sdk level are you using? You need level 24 or above to use it. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Comment: Boom! Thats where I was going wrong. I'm using an android-22 emulator! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

In android studio, **Instant Run** can affect your code

Try to disable it via the below:

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run

,

The Cowboy.

Comment: I'm running gradle from a CI environment - it runs fine locally.

Comment: Try removing the .gradle folder from project.

Comment: Then clean and reinstall